# Save workbook`s sheets as single files in root folder, as xlsx and pdf

Tags: excel, vba

I tried this coding without succes - any good ideas??

```
Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()

Sub SavePlan()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Main")
    
    Dim FolderPath As String: FolderPath = wb.Path
    Dim dFileName As String: dFileName = sws.Range("C6").Value
    Dim dFilePath As String
    dFilePath = FolderPath & Application.PathSeparator & dFileName
    
    sws.Copy ' copy to a new (destination) workbook
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
    dwb.SaveAs Filename:=dFilePath
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False

    MsgBox "Worksheet backed up.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by `without succes`? What is expected and what is the result? Any errors? If so, any error messages?

Comment: Does `dFilePath` contain the file extension, too? Since, you talk about "xlsx and pdf", may I assume that it doesn't? Please, copy the content of `sws.Range("C6").value` and paste it in your question or in a comment.

Comment: Do you really need help?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Please, try using the next adapted code. It assumes that `dFilePath` does not contain any extension. If it does, you must tell us what it is and I can adapt the code:

```
Sub SavePlan()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Main")
    
    Dim FolderPath As String: FolderPath = wb.Path
    Dim dFileName As String: dFileName = sws.Range("C6").value
    Dim dFilePath As String
    dFilePath = FolderPath & Application.PathSeparator & dFileName 'no extension...
    
    sws.Copy ' it creates a new workbook containing only the copied sheet
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ActiveWorkbook
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
      dwb.saveas FileName:=dFilePath & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault
      dwb.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=dFilePath & ".pdf", _
                Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    dwb.Close False

    MsgBox "Worksheet backed up.", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: @Flemming Staal Didn't you find some time to answer clarification questions or test the above code? If tested, didn't it do what you need?